# Maven War Plugin Websphere

Tags: java, maven, websphere, rad

I am trying to get a Rational Application Developer project to run on a websphere server. I am trying to get the `maven-war-plugin` to work. However, when trying to start the server, websphere can not find the UI Files. I have my plugin here:

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <webappDirectory>WebContent</webappDirectory>
                <source>/codeCoverageUI2/src/</source>
                <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

I feel the issue is with my `webappDirectory` but I do not know what else to put it to, besides the location of all my UI files.

Anyone have some insight?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using WebSphere Classic V8 or earlier?
What we recommend because when developing a project in RAD/WDT, WAS Classic requires building the project in a "Single Root" structure.  Add the following to your pom:

```
<build>
   <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes</outputDirectory>
   <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
...
```

This will build your source within the Web content folder.   (Make sure you do a Project -> "Maven" -> "Update Project...") then rebuild...

Comment: yeah we are using websphere 7, I'll update my question with the changes you suggested. I did that and now I just see an error on my Java Resourses folder, yet not code is in error